# BigQuery Slow Response on API

Tags: php, database, amazon-ec2, google-bigquery, bigdata

I am using **Google BigQuery** as a Secondary Database for my application to store large data, i am facing problem in that my query is,

```
> SELECT `column_name` FROM `project.dataset.tbl_nm` WHERE partition_key = value AND cluster_key = value;
```

This is a simple **SELECT** query, if am firing this query through the bigquery console then it gives the result immediately and when i am firing this same query using [Google BigQuery PHP SDK](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-bigquery) then it gives result too slow like it takes minimum 6 to 7 seconds, i am using **AWS EC2** as a server, I don't know where the problem occurs like i have placed time logs everywhere and checked the results then i got to know only that total 6 to 7 seconds spends on the get query result, please suggest if anyone have faced similar issue or have any suggestions, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Your UI is returning cached data, your api runs your query.
6-7 seconds is not that bad, usually its 3-4 seconds.

Try to see if your python library offers other ways to run the query, as in bigquery you can run a async and sync way a query. A wrong timing on the pooling can escalate to 5-6 seconds.

Comment: I have disabled "Use cached result" in the BigQuery UI. However, when I tried another query, I encountered the same issue. The UI provides a response in 8 seconds, but the API takes 15 to 16 seconds almost double. I am unable to figure out the problem. Additionally, I am using BigQuery's PHP SDK, but I am not getting the desired response as efficient as UI.